# How to either "close", dispose or vanish an open form in NetBeans 6.8

Tags: java, forms, netbeans, dispose

I am very new with NetBeans 6.8 and I'm in the process of recreating a pre-existing game. I want to open a new form while closing an pre-existing (open) form with the click of a button, I've tried various methods of going about this and none of them have seemed to work for me. I personally believe my problem is due to my lack of knowledge although I've seen many others with similar confusion. I also think my problem lies within calling my currently opened form which im honestly not 100% sure how to call, in this instance I used "this." but I dont think it got the job done. If anyone could shine some light on this situation it would be greatly appreciated.

**And here is a copy of my buttons code.**

```
private void btnPlayMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    //Defining and calling new form.
    ButtonView s = new ButtonView();
    s.setVisible(true);
    //Setting current form to "invisible".
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: What is the form Object(JPanel, JFrame)? Where do you instantiate it? In which class do you run this code?

Comment: I believe the form is a JFrame and it is in my source folder with the other JFrame form (ButtonView). I run this code in its own "public class".

Comment: I've moved on from this problem, instead of having 2 separate forms I just fit everything into 1 so this is no longer a problem for me.

Comment: is the problem solved now/? If yes you can close this question